# Help me with Php session vs Header redirect?

Tags: php

I have the following pages:

#### page1.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['link'])) { 
session_start(); 
$_session['myvariable'] = 'Hello World'; 
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/page2.php'); 
exit; 
} 
?> 
<a href="<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?link=yes';?>">Click Here</a>
```

#### page2.php

```
<?php 
print 'Here is page two, and my session variable: '; 
session_start(); 
print $_session['myvariable']; //This line could not output.
exit; 
?>
```

When I try output `$_session['myvariable']` I did not get the result hello world message.

I could not find out the solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_start() has to be called before you send any output as it relies upon cookies to store the ID.

Also $_SESSION is uppercase

Comment: Although in this very case it isn't an issue

Comment: In page2 he is printing before calling session_start. the incorrect casing of $_SESSION is probably the main issue here, but this could still be affecting him.

Comment: Affecting what? what would prevent from reading session value?

Answer (score 4):

`$_SESSION` not `$_session`. Uppercase.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script always helps in such case

Comment: Unlike function names, variable names are case-sensible in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['myvariable'];

echo 'Here is page two, and my session variable: '; 
exit;
?>
```

HTTP headers must be the very first output, so `session_start()` must be at the top of your code.

Other notes:
* $_SESSION should be uppercase.
* Echo > print

Comment: What do you mean "Echo > print"?